# Dynamically derive a class in python

Tags: python, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python dynamic inheritance: How to choose base class upon instance creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057019/python-dynamic-inheritance-how-to-choose-base-class-upon-instance-creation)

I want a class to choose a base class on the fly based on a parameter in the **init** method.

```
Class A():
    #...
Class B():
    #...
Class C():
    def __init__(self, base_type):
        if parent_type == 'A':
            #TODO: make C derive A
        else:
            #TODO: make C derive B
```

A and B are library classes that derive the same base class.

The answers to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057019/python-dynamic-inheritance-how-to-choose-base-class-upon-instance-creation) seemed too ugly.

Comment: Why would you do something like this? Although many things are possible in a dynamic language like python, this does not seem as a good way to go with. With some more context, we might be able to better understand your problem and offer a solution.

Comment: Do you really need to use inheritance? Could you use composition instead (e.g. have each C instance own an instance of either A or B)? Check out the second, highly rated answer to the question you linked.

Comment: If you insist on not using a factory pattern, you may want to investigate metaclasses.  http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses

Comment: @cyroxx I just added an important detail that A and B are library classes that derive the same base class.

Comment: Similar question is more or less exactly the same, and provides all the answers you're going to get here... if the answer is 'ugly', your question should address what you find ugly about those soltuions, not just 'give me new answers to the same question'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean base_type insteand of parent type. But the following should work

```
Class C():
    def __init__(self, base_type):
        if base_type == 'A':
            self.__class__=A
        else:
            self.__class__=B
```

Some more details on this approach can be found here: http://harkablog.com/dynamic-state-machines.html

Answer (score 2):

While you can change the class in `__init__`, it's more appropriate to do it in `__new__`. The former is for initialising, the latter for construction:

```
class A(object): pass
class B(object): pass

class C(object):
    def __new__(cls, base_type, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(C, cls).__new__(base_type, *args, **kwargs)

assert isinstance( C(A), A )
assert isinstance( C(B), B )
```

With `__init__`, you're creating an instance of C, and then modifying its type. With `__new__`, you're never creating an instance of C, just the required `base_type`.

Comment: But `assert isinstance(C(A), C)` will raise an AssertionError

Answer (score 0):

I am completely agree with cyroxx, you should give us some context to your problem. As it stands now, `__init__` is called after the instance of the class is created to initialize its members. Too late to change the inheritance.

Would a simple class factory be enough for you:

```
class MyA(ABMixin, A): pass

class MyB(ABMixin, B): pass

def factory(class_type):
    if class_type == 'A':
        return MyA()
    else:
        return MyB()
```

I suggest to read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949) about dynamic class creation in python.