# How to choose python base class dynamically?

Tags: python, selenium, inheritance

In python (3) I want to create a derived class dynamically from several base classes.

Concrete example: In `selenium`, in order to run GUI based tests, you can initiate a driver from e.g Firefox or Chrome in the following way:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Now I want to create a derived class to which additional functionalities are added. Something like

```
class MyDriver(webdriver.Firefox):
    def find_button_and_click_on_it_no_matter_what(self, params):
        ...
```

But the base class can be either the `firefox` driver or the chrome `driver`. I found something related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099237/dynamically-derive-a-class-in-python), but it does not seem to work:

```
class MyDriver(object):
    def __new__(cls, base_type, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(HBPDriver, cls).__new__(base_type, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Calling this command

```
driver = mydriver.MyDriver(webdriver.Firefox())
```

gives an error

```
TypeError: object.__new__(X): X is not a type object (WebDriver)
```

How to do it right? And how to call `__init__` on the derived class...?

I hope it is clear what I want to achieve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you call `__new__` it is too late to choose the class to instantiate; `__new__` is an *attribute* of the class. Instead you need a trivial factory function:

```
def my_driver(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    class NewThing(cls):
        ...
    return NewThing(*args, **kwargs)

ff = my_driver(webdriver.Firefox)
```

Another option is to define the base class with an expression:

```
if ...:
  base = webdriver.Firefox
elif ...:
  base = webdriver.Chrome
class MyDriver(base):
    ...
```

A third option is to skip the `class` statement and use `type` directly, although I wouldn't recommend this unless the body of the class statement was going to be empty.

```
class MyDriver(base):
    pass
```

is equivalent to `MyDriver = type('MyDriver', (base,), {})`.

Comment: Tanks for the options - but where/how can I define additional class methods in the first option?

Comment: The first option, to some extent, is a wrapper around the other two (except it didn't define a subclass, but did instantiate the object). I've updated it to show how it uses the same idea as the second example to define a new class locally in the function.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I would say these are same ways to do it. Anyway, your suggestion seems to work...